# Use Linear Approximation to estimate $\Delta f=f(3.02)-f(3)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, linear-approximation

I have a homework question that is asking to use the linear approximation to estimate $\Delta f=f(3.02)-f(3)$ for $f(x)=x^2$.

I know that the linear approximation is $L(x) = f'(a)(x-a)+f(a)$.

I however do not quit understand what the problem is asking in the first place. Couldn't I just estimate $\Delta f=f(3.02)-f(3)$, by plugging both 3.02 and 3 into the original function of $f(x) = x^2$ and subtracting them. How do I do this with linear approximation?

Comment: The problem is asking you to compute $L(3.02)-f(3)$. Yes, you can compute the exact different trivially, presumably your instructor wanted you to see that the linear approximation is reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the linear approximation $L$ for $f$, we have
$$\Delta f := f(x) - f(a) \approx L(x) - L(a) = L(x) - f(a) = f'(a) (x - a).$$
(Notice that the last equality is just the rearrangement of the linear approximation formula
$$L(x) = f'(a) (x - a) + f(a).)$$

In your case,
$$f'(3) = \left.2x \right\vert_{x = 3} = 2(3) = 6,$$
and hence substituting in the above formula gives
$$\Delta f = f(3.02) - f(3) \approx (6)((3.02) - 3) = 6(0.02) = \boxed{0.12}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\Delta f}{0.02}&=\frac{f(3.02)-f(3)}{0.02}\\
&=\frac{f(3+0.02)-f(3)}{0.02}\\
&\approx \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(3+h)-f(3)}{h}\\
&=f'(3)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed compute: $$f(3.02)-f(3) = (3.02)^2-3^2 = (6.02)\cdot 0.02 = 0.1204,$$ the exact value. The point of the exercise is *avoiding* this computations. Using linear approximation gives: $$L(3.02) = f(3) + f'(3)\cdot0.02,$$ so that $\Delta f \approx f'(3)\cdot 0.02 = 6 \cdot 0.02 = 0.12$. Good, no?

Answer (score -1):

here is what you can do to approximate $3.02^2 - 3^2$ using difference of squares:

$$3.02^2 - 3^2 = (3.02 - 3)(3.02 + 3) \simeq 0.02*6 = 0.12 $$